# How to export nested gridview to excel/word with gridlines on the child grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have tried posting questions on different forum, but there are still no response.. can anyone help me really? i have tried most codings i gathered on exporting nested gridview.. however most of them gave me the same output.. in fact what i want was quite "simple"

code(excel)

```
protected void Export(GridView gridView)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "StaffAppraisal.xls"));
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

    //  Create a table to contain the grid
    Table table = new Table();

    //  include the gridline settings
    table.GridLines = gridView.GridLines;

    //  add the header row to the table
    if (gridView.HeaderRow != null)
    {
        PrepareControlForExport(gridView.HeaderRow);
        gridView.HeaderRow.Style.Add("background-color", "");
        table.Rows.Add(gridView.HeaderRow);
    }

    //  add each of the data rows to the table

    foreach (GridViewRow row in gridView.Rows)
    {
        PrepareControlForExport(row);
        table.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    //  add the footer row to the table
    if (gridView.FooterRow != null)
    {
        PrepareControlForExport(gridView.FooterRow);
        table.Rows.Add(gridView.FooterRow);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= gridView.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        table.Rows[i].Cells[0].Visible = false;
    }

    using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter())
    {
        using (HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter))
        {
            //  render the table into the htmlwriter
            table.RenderControl(htmlWriter);

            //  render the htmlwriter into the response
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(stringWriter.ToString());
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

code(word)

```
public static void Export(GridView gridView)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "StaffAppraisal.doc"));
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-word";
    //  Create a table to contain the grid
    Table table = new Table();

    //  include the gridline settings
    table.GridLines = gridView.GridLines;

    //  add the header row to the table
    if (gridView.HeaderRow != null)
    {
        PrepareControlForExport(gridView.HeaderRow);
        table.Rows.Add(gridView.HeaderRow);
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < gridView.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        //Apply style to Individual Cells
        gridView.HeaderRow.Cells[j].Style.Add("background-color", "black");
    }

    //  add each of the data rows to the table
    foreach (GridViewRow row in gridView.Rows)
    {
        PrepareControlForExport(row);
        table.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    //  add the footer row to the table
    if (gridView.FooterRow != null)
    {
        PrepareControlForExport(gridView.FooterRow);
        table.Rows.Add(gridView.FooterRow);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= gridView.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        table.Rows[i].Cells[0].Visible = false;
    }

    using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter())
    {
        using (HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter))
        {
            //  render the table into the htmlwriter
            table.RenderControl(htmlWriter);

            //  render the htmlwriter into the response
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(stringWriter.ToString());
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

the image below is exported from excel...

[image: exported to excel]

the image below is exported from word...

[image: exported to word]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

omg after testing for so many days, i finally found the solution: add `CellSpacing="2"` to gridview design and that's all.

Comment: Hi I know this is an old post. But can you please share "PrepareControlForExport" function's definition?